# Mybatis: how to concat <include refid /> with String in mapper.xml？

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I'm working on a spring web project with mybatis. I have many split tables like  user_10, user_11, user_12

in mapper.xml, I have

```
   <sql id="TableNameBase">user_</sql>

   <insert id="insert">
     INSERT INTO <include refid="TableNameBase">#{id}
     ...
```

for exmaple, if I want to do something like：

```
     insert into user_10 ...
```

I can pass id=10 
but the above `<include refid="TableNameBase">#{id}` seems to produce `user_ 10` instead of expected `user_10`

what can I do?

Comment: Is the problem the whitespace within the `user_10` tablename?

Comment: it seems to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the  tag adds spaces before and after.
What you can do is to define a parametric table name like this:

```
<sql id="user_table">
  user_#{id}
</sql>
```

Then you can use it by passing the parameter, like in the following example:

```
<insert id="insert">
     INSERT INTO <include refid="user_table"/>
     ...
```

Comment: in another sql statement, there is `table_name= <include refid="user_table"/>`, but this has no single quotes '', so it is not OK. I tried `table_name= ' <include refid="user_table"/>'`, but I got `table_name=          '  user_10 '` but not `table_name='user_10'`, how to deal with this?

Comment: As far as I can see, in this code `table_name= ' <include refid="user_table"/>'`  there is a space before the `<include.../>`. By the way, since this code seems part of a where condition (not the same scenario of the question), It's better to pass it to the query as a parameter value and not using the include for a parameter value.